# stylesheet cache using XML management interface is not working

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am trying to flush the stylesheet cache using XML management Interface (SOMA).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:man="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <man:request domain="mydomain">
     <man:do-action>
        <FlushStylesheetCache>
           <XMLManager class="default"></XMLManager>
        </FlushStylesheetCache>
     </man:do-action>
  </man:request>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Getting error `<log-event level="error">Stylesheet name '' is not valid</log-event>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have given wrong class type and null object name.

```
<man:do-action>
        <FlushStylesheetCache>
           <XMLManager class="XMLManager">default</XMLManager>
        </FlushStylesheetCache>
</man:do-action>
```

class value can be null. As it is option value for this request. You should have XML Management access to flush the cache using XML management interface

Comment: This was very helpful, can you provide online resource from where you got this.